# how to loop and decrypt gpg files in a batch

Tags: windows, batch, zip, gnupg

Im trying to decrypt all gpg in a folder, but cant figure how to build a batch to read all gpg files and  extract they in .zip files.

```
What I have: 
xxx1.zip.gpg 
yyy.zip.gpg 
dddd.zip.gpg
```

What I want:

```
xxx1.zip
yyy.zip
ddd.zip
```

the cmd line I could do is:

```
gpg --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase "mypassword"  --output  myfiles.zip  --decrypt  myfiles.zip.gpg
```

How to do a batch withh a loop and replace "myfiles" with all my gpg files??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this loop (tested) to do this job for you

```bath
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_gpg=gpg.exe --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`%___AppDir__%where.exe .:*.zip.gpg
    `)do %_gpg% "mypassword" --output "%%~dpi%%~ni" --decrypt "%%~i"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following (untested) code should do the job.

Create a `.bat` file within the folder, paste the following into it and
run it:

```
for %%i in (*.gpg) do (
  set "file=%%i"
  gpg --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase "mypassword" --output "%file:.gpg=%" --decrypt "%%i"
)
```

Notes: I suggest to take a backup of the folder, before running this
batch file. I have not verified your `gpg` command.